# How to make sure the rx java observable is not run again until the first call finishes

Tags: android, rx-java, android-syncadapter

We have a sync in a sync adapter.  Once the sync is called we need to block any other calls, from the OS, to that sync adapter until we have finished handling the response from the first sync.  I thought that calling .blockingGet() on a Single would do the trick, but it doesn't.  How can I make sure that all code being handled in the Single finishes before we allow the Single to be called/subscribed to again?

```
@Override
public void onPerformTrackedSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
     try {
        mCurrentUpdater = createUpdater();
        mCurrentUpdater
                .update()
                .blockingGet();
        onSyncCompleted(null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        onSyncCompleted(ex);
        onError(ex);
    }
}

@NonNull
public final Single<Complete> update() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mUpdateCalled) throw new IllegalStateException("Updaters should not be reused");
        mUpdateCalled = true;
    }
    updateOnePage(); // will call onUpdaterPageSuccess which can continue updating
    return mCompleteSubject
            .take(1)
            .singleOrError();
}

   /**
 * Update an individual "page" of data. Calls to onUpdaterPageSuccess may call back into this function.
*/
void updateOnePage() {
    updateNextPage()
            .subscribe(
                    this::onUpdaterPageSuccess,
                    this::onPageFailure
            );
}
```

This is were the actual network sync is called:

```
protected Single<Page> updateNextPage() {
    runMigrations();
    String syncMarker = AreaSyncService.getSyncMarker();
    Log.i("AAAZ", "Area Sync Requested  " + Thread.currentThread());
    return buildRequestData(new Date())
            .flatMap(requestData -> mSalesRabbitService.syncAreas(syncMarker,
                    requestData.syncedAreas,
                    requestData.syncedAreaUserHistories,
                    requestData.deletedAreaIds,
                    requestData.deletedAreaUserHistoryIds)
                    .map(areaSyncValidated -> Pair.create(areaSyncValidated, requestData)))
            .map(pair -> new Page(pair.first, pair.second))
            .flatMap(this::updateWithPage);
}
```

And here we handle the sync response with another Single

```
protected Single<Page> updateWithPage(@NonNull Page page) {
    Log.i("AAAZ", "Area Sync Requested  " + Thread.currentThread());
    return Single.just(page)
           .flatMap(this::updateIdTrackersAndLastAreaSyncDevice)
           .flatMap(this::addAreaIdsToNewAreas)
           .flatMap(this::addAreaUserHistoryIdsToNewAreaUserHistories)
           .flatMap(this::updateAreas)
           .flatMap(this::updateHistories)
           .flatMap(this::createAreas)
           .flatMap(this::createHistories)
           .flatMap(this::resetCacheFirstTime)
           .flatMap(this::postChangedEvents)
           .flatMap(this::handleDeletionsResetCachePostEvent)
           .flatMap(this::housekeepingIfApplicable);
}
```

I suspect the issue is something I'm doing wrong between the update() method and the updateOnePage() method.  How can I make sure that the single subscribed() to in updateOnePage() finishes completely before it can be called again?

Answer (score 0):

As part of your observer chain, where the queries are being constructed, at the end of `updateNextPage()`, you have a `flatMap()` operator that invokes `updateOnePage()`. `flatMap()` takes an additional argument which is the number of parallel operations. Add the parameter 1.

```
.flatMap(this::updateWithPage, 1);
```

Comment: It appears Single<> does not have a flatMap(Function, int).  Would it be worth it to change my Single<Page> to Observable<Page>?

Comment: Yes, it would be worth it.